# How can I profile GTK applications?

Tags: linux, profiling, gtk3

I recently switched to Linux and have been trying several open source projects. One of the applications I tried is a GTK3 application for RAW photo editing. However, while being quick at doing calculations in general, it has significant input lag. When clicking, dragging, or hovering it takes a noticeable time for the GUI to respond. As it is open source, I would like to spend some time and try to figure out if I can fix this. However, I am stuck at the first step. I do not know how to get frame profiling data for the program.

Thus, my question:
How can I get profiling data for this app? I was considering using https://optick.dev/ however as GTK is event based, this does not seem to be the right choice.

**Note:**
I need a solution for Linux and GTK3. However, I will award the solution to the answer which explains profiling for the most systems (Linux, Mac, Windows, ?) and GTK versions.

Comment: I don't know about any Gtk-oriented profiling tools, but you can try `perf`. Afaik it can track specific threads, try tracking the main loop. Another approach would be using `gtk-inspector` to find a widget which is lagging and examining it's source to find if there is some heavy computation in gui thread

Comment: Hmm... Someone posted an answer about a tool called `sysprof` a couple of days ago. I got as far as downloading it, but then did not have the time to review it. Now the post is gone... Trying the tool, it does the bare minimum of what I want (showing how much each function gets called), however I would much prefer to see the time spend inside instead of the number of calls.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev I had a look at `perf`. It seems very complicated. Is there any GUI for it? I do not want to start plotting data myself... `gtk-inspector` allows me to track down GUI elements, which is very helpful, but I did not see any performance options in there. Did I somehow miss them?